# How to query and retrieve data in order by 2-layer child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Because I want to create a leaderboard in my android app, I started learning firebase recently and have created a database as shown. Here I have several registered users; under the "user" node are the userUIDs of each user, and under the userUID node are the datas of each user. I was planning to achieve making the leaderboard by querying all the objects under the "users" node and sorting them by their "total IMPs", but the problem is that "totalIMPs" is not a direct child of the "users" node, and thus I cannot use such code as:

```
Query query = databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("totalIMPs");
```

to achieve this. Is there any alternative way I can do this "without changing" the structure of my database? Thank you.

Comment: Actually, that query is exactly what you need. Have you tried it? Is it not working?

Answer (score -3):

First: Firebase - when you're adding informatrion ,firebase adds like a mess.

If you wanna order your database in a query, at the moment when you get the information from firebase,

you need to investigate in  **Range Queries**, and  **Limit Queries**, I prefer the example in the old console of firebase, in this part you can find a very simple example, and focus on the result ...

Link of the topic **Range Queries**, and  **Limit Queries**:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data

The difference between the old and the new version is very small, so you can start with this logic.

If you wanna order the data when you try to add the information, you will need to know the low value and the max value, and the same.. **Range Queries**, and  **Limit Queries**.

We can order nodes by a child key that they all share by passing that key to orderByChild(). For example, using our sample database of dinosaur facts, we can read all dinosaurs ordered by height using the following query:

```
   var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key() + " was " + snapshot.val().height + " meters tall");
});
```

Reference: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbychild.html

We can order nodes by the value of their children using the orderByValue() method. For example, using the dino sports score data in our sample database of dinosaur facts, we can display the top three scoring dinosaurs using the following query:

```
var scoresRef = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/scores");
scoresRef.orderByValue().limitToLast(3).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log("The " + data.key() + " dinosaur's score is " + data.val());
  });
});
```